# Is there a way to activate a trigger from inside a trigger with a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have an 'A' table that has a trigger to extract information from a document that is in pdf that was uploaded to my program. However, sometimes this pdf file has more than one document. So I did a stored procedure at the end of the trigger that separated the documents within a same pdf file and so re-inserted into the table 'A' another line containing a new document to activate the trigger. My problem: The trigger is not activated again, table 'A' undergoes changes but the trigger is not activated.

Comment: What do you mean your trigger is not activated? Think of a trigger like an event. It fires when something happens to a table. So if you have a trigger for INSERT it will NOT fire for an UPDATE. If you need help you should start by reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Odds are, you need to turn on the Recursive Triggers option in your database.

By default, if a trigger modifies the same table where the trigger was created, the trigger will not fire again. To allow this to happen, use:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase 
SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS ON;
```

Note: This can cause issues if you have a trigger that directly modifies its table. If this is, or could be, a problem then an alternate solution would be to place the action that you hope will activate the trigger into a queue, and let the trigger activate naturally.